# md-card : How to align contents in row and column inside md-card-content?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, angular-material2

How can I align the below md-card-content in 2 rows and 2 columns? I want the  ID and Value to be displayed in a single row and Time and Result in the second row.

```
   <md-card-content>
    <h2>ID:</h2>
    <h2>Value:</h2> 
    <h2>Time:</h2> 
    <h2>Result:</h2>
    </md-card-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do these styles and Make sure that to override material styles and not to replace other than these elements.

```
md-card-content {
    display: flex;
    font-size: 0;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    margin:-10px 0 0 -10px;
}
h2 {
    display: inline-block;
    background:blue;
    margin:10px 0 0 10px;
    flex-grow: 1;
    min-height:100px; // or max-height as per your requirement
    width: calc(100% * (1/2) - 10px - 1px)
}
```